# Mi index no puede encontrar los archivos en los repositorios de mi web

Tags: rutas, required, activedirectory

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'includes/head.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/lupagency.com/public_html/index.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/lupagency.com/public_html/index.php on line 1

este es el error principal, me dice que no encuentra los archivos, pero la ruta es correcta, no se que hacer jaja

Necesito que los archivos con el atriuto require(""), sean capaz de conectar el resto de los archivos.